# How do I modify the perspective of an OpenGL using gluLookAt()?

Tags: python, opengl

I want to change the angles at which I view the models I create. I looked around and found out about the gluLookAt() function, which I think does what I wan't to do. However, I have absolutely no idea how to use gluLookAt(). I popped it into my code below, but I can't seem to get it to function properly. Anyway, my code (python):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GLU import *

import pygame

def pyramid():

    #draw a pyramid here

def cube():

    #draw a cube here

class mainClass():
    def mainMethod(self):   
        from sys import exit

        print ("Initalizing...")

        resolution = (400, 300)

        pygame.init()
        screen = pygame.display.set_mode(resolution, pygame.OPENGL|pygame.DOUBLEBUF)

        self.xPer, self.yPer, self.zPer = 0, 0, 0
        print ("Doing GL stuff...")
        glViewport(self.xPer, self.yPer, resolution[0], resolution[1])

        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
        glLoadIdentity()
        gluPerspective(45.0, float(resolution[0]) / resolution[1], 0.1, 1000.0)#Distance, 

        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
        glLoadIdentity()

        print ("More GL stuff...")
        glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)

        #glHint(GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL_NICEST)

        glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH)
        glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)

        print ("Minor details...")
        clock = pygame.time.Clock()

        rot_tri = 0
        rot_quad = 0

        print ("Mainloop...")
        while True:

            for event in pygame.event.get():

                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    pygame.quit()
                    exit()
                if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                    if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                        pygame.quit()
                        exit()
                    elif event.key == pygame.K_a:
                        self.xPer += 50

                    elif event.key == pygame.K_d:
                        self.xPer -= 50
                        #glViewport(self.xPer, self.yPer, resolution[0], resolution[1])
                    elif event.key == pygame.K_w:
                        self.yPer -= 50
                        #glViewport(self.xPer, self.yPer, resolution[0], resolution[1])
                    elif event.key == pygame.K_s:
                        self.yPer += 50
                        #glViewport(self.xPer, self.yPer, resolution[0], resolution[1])
                    elif event.key == pygame.K_f:
                        self.zPer += 50
                    elif event.key == pygame.K_v:
                        self.zPer -= 50


            glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

            glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
            glLoadIdentity()
            gluLookAt(10, 10, 10, self.xPer, self.yPer, self.zPer, 0, 1, -1);

            glLoadIdentity()
            glTranslatef(-1.5, 0.0, -6.0)
            glRotatef(rot_tri, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0)
            pyramid()

            glLoadIdentity()
            glTranslate(1.5, 0.0, -6.0)
            glRotatef(rot_quad, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0)
            cube()

            rot_tri += 2.0
            rot_quad -= 1.5

            pygame.display.set_caption("hello_opengl.py FPS: %i" % clock.get_fps())

            pygame.display.flip()
            clock.tick()

t = mainClass()
t.mainMethod()
```

All I want this code to do is modify the angle at which I view some rotating pyramids and cubes. Can anyone explain how to modify this code to use gluLookAt()?

PS: Is there a nice page which explains OpenGL (Matrices, 3d math, whatever glLoadIdentity() does, etc)?  I can write the code, but I have no idea what I'm doing.

Comment: if you grok C, try [the red book](http://www.glprogramming.com/red/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are totally missing the point of `gluLookAt`. You have to call it once on the current matrix, then *don't* clean it and modify it so the other object are drawn accordingly.

When you do:

```
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
gluLookAt(10, 10, 10, ...); // <-- this line has no effect
glLoadIdentity();
```

`gluLookAt` functions just as `glRotate` and `glTranslate` functions.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand... Could you explain this a little bit more in depth?

Comment: I'll take a look at it, but could you please explain what lines of my code I should modify to get gluLookAt() to work?

Comment: I will tell you if you tell me which buttons i have to press and in which order.

Comment: Ok, I get it you don't feel like spoon feeding me. At least tell me what in my code is making the gluLookAt() line ineffective.

Comment: the `glLoadIdentity()` is erasing the modelview matrix state back to identity matrix, obviously.

Comment: Sorry, nothing's obvious to me. I'm just starting out. Thanks for the help though, i guess... Now to change code around and see what happens

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24973/discussion-between-pipsqueaker117-and-bartek-banachewicz)