# openGL transformation and gluLookAt()

Tags: opengl

I have a studying project which represents simple 3D scene. I want to draw sphere in some non-origin point. Later I'm going implement this as separate function or method.

I'm setting point of view using `gluLookAt()` then I'm transforming model-view matrix using `glTranslatef()` with little offset and drawing sphere. Unfortunately, the sphere isn't shown. Am I right with model-view matrix approaching?

```
void display(void){    
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluLookAt(1, 0 ,1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0);    
    glColor3b(197, 96, 63);    
    glPushMatrix(); 
    glLoadIdentity();
    glTranslatef(0.1, 0, 0);
    glutWireSphere(0.2, 20, 10);
    glPopMatrix();     
    glFlush();
}

void reshape(int w, int h){
    glViewport(0, 0, (GLsizei) w, (GLsizei) h);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho ((float)w/(float)h, (float)-w/(float)h, -1, 1, 0.8, 100);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/15006905/752976

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you aren't.

```
gluLookAt(1, 0 ,1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0); 
glColor3b(197, 96, 63);    
glPushMatrix(); 
glLoadIdentity(); // why it should be there?
```

By zeroing the view matrix there, you are drawing your object relatively to the origin coordinates, **not taking your glLookAt** into account. The call to it is effectively ignored. It should be coded as:

1. Set up the "camera matrix"
2. Push the matrix on the stack
3. Translate to the object's position
4. Draw the object
5. Pop and go back to 2.

So if you want to set up hypothetical "camera", you have to *combine* positions of objects with the camera matrix itself.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach doesn't look that unreasonable. The problem is here:

```
glPushMatrix(); 
glLoadIdentity();
glTranslatef(0.1, 0, 0);
```

The pushing (and later popping) is a good idea, but by setting the matrix to identity before the translation, you loose any transformations done before, in particular the viewing transformations established with `gluLookAt`. So just remove this `glLoadIdentity` to properly concatenate the individual transformations.

Always keep in mind that all the matrix transformation functions, like `glTranslate`, `glOrtho`, or `gluLookat` always modify the currently selected (with `glMatrixMode`) matrix and don't just replace it. This is also the reason why you do a `glLoadIdentity` before the calls to `glOrtho` and `gluLookAt`.